# How to add a name field for a shop database (OOP/C++)

Tags: c++, oop

Ok, so I've made a database type program and created an item number and price field. I've also tried to stick to a primary key by using the index values of the array of both the "item number" field and "price". But was wondering how to add an "Item name" field along with this to make it work. I've tried to think of many different ways of adding a char type array but that doesn't really work.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class shop
{
    private:
        int i,n, item[20];
        float price[20];
    public:
        void input();
        void output();
};
void shop::input()
{
    cout<<"Enter the number of items: ";
    cin>>n;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the item number of the " << i << " item: ";
        cin >> item[i];
        cout << "Enter the price of the item: ";
        cin >> price[i];
    }

}
void shop::output()
{
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Item Number: " << item[i] << endl;
        cout << "Price: " << price[i] << endl << endl;
    }
}
void main()
{
    class shop s;
    s.input();
    s.output();
}
```

Comment: A small design thing: Wouldn't it be better to have a separate `item` class, that contains all information about the "item", and then have a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of the `items` in the `shop` class?

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, but I was wondering if there may be a way to go around this without actually using the string or vector header files.

If possible I'd like to use an array of characters. Like I've tried 2D arrays to get me to achieve this but I don't know how to input and ouput them.

Comment: Yes, old C-style strings with a fixed-size array. Or using a pointer and dynamically allocate memory. It does have some problems though, that you won't have by using e.g. [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class or struct to hold the data:

```
struct Item
{
    int id;
    float price;     // float may lead to rounding errors.
                     // I would use int and store cents
    //string name;
    // If you really want to use c-style string
    char name[20];
    // or
    // char *name;   // You would need to use new with this
};
```

Then keep an array of these:

```
class shop
{
    private:
        Item items[20];
        // As mentioned, better than a static array would be a vector
        //std::vector<Item> items;
    public:
        void input();
        void output();
};
```

Comment: C-style array is bad advice IMHO!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why? Would you prefer a class?

Comment: I would prefer a `std::array<Item,20>` for fixed size, or a `std::vector<Item>` for variable sized.

Comment: Oh, ok. I misunderstood your comment. Yes, I agree. Didn't want to change OPs code too much.

Comment: I agree with you Johnny Mopp, out of all the things that can be considered vectors are best to use. Thanks for your help and the detailed comments.

Comment: @Khaleel78 [We are happy to help.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

What about a vector of strings?

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class shop
{
    private:
        int i,n, item[20];
        float price[20];
        vector<string> names;
    public:
        void input();
        void output();
};
void shop::input()
{
    cout<<"Enter the number of items: ";
    cin>>n;
    names.resize(n);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the item number of the " << i << " item: ";
        cin >> item[i];
        cout << "Enter the price of the item: ";
        cin >> price[i];
        cout << "Enter the name of the item: ";
        cin >> names[i];
    }
}
void shop::output()
{
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Item Number: " << item[i] << endl;
        cout << "Price: " << price[i] << endl << endl;
        cout << "Name: " << names[i] << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

And it would be good to have a destructor to clean the memory taken by the vector.

Comment: Looking at the original code I'd say `item`, `price`, and `name` should be put into a class and instances of that class should be managed in a vector. Otherwise you have to change `item` and `price` to `std::vector` as well which isn't the most optimal approach.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I agree, and this approach is already shown by Johnny Mopp

Answer (score 0):

I would use std::string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class shop
{
    private:
        int i,n, item[20];
        float price[20];
        string name[20];
    public:
        void input();
        void output();
};
void shop::input()
{
    cout<<"Enter the number of items: ";
    cin>>n;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the item number of the " << i << " item: ";
        cin >> item[i];
        cout << "Enter the name of the item: ";
        cin >> name[i];
        cout << "Enter the price of the item: ";
        cin >> price[i];
    }

}
void shop::output()
{
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Item Number: " << item[i] << endl;
        cout << "Item Name: " << name[i] << endl;
        cout << "Price: " << price[i] << endl << endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    class shop s;
    s.input();
    s.output();
}
```

Comment: C-style array is bad advice IMHO!